# I cant fix normals - Blender to Unity?

Tags: mesh, normals, unity

Ok, Ive looked at all the tutorials, turned on blackface culling in Blender so that I could see the holes that show up in Unity, and taken these steps to fix normals in Blender:

1. Recalculated normals
2. Flipped normals
3. Turned on the "show normals" option so I can verify the normals are THERE:

[image]

But no matter what, exporting to fbx with these settings (I have to do old FBX):

[image]

I STILL get holes in Unity. I have no idea where to turn. No holes in blender but unity:

[image]

Unity import settings are:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import a .blend file into Unity, or did you export as FBX? I had the same issue, but with a FBX file it worked.